# Posting picture to facebook Graph API using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook-graph-api

I try to get the image upload to facebook working... Unfortunately, the facebook graph API always returns the following error:

```
{ error: Objectcode: 324, message: "(#324) Requires upload file", type: "OAuthException" }
```

It seems that the picture data is not transfered correctly. The facebook docs tell me to use a multipart/form-data upload. (See [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/photos) > Publishing)

I am using [angular-easyfb](https://github.com/pc035860/angular-easyfb) as a wrapper for the faceebook sdk. What's the easiest way to get this thing working? My current code is:

```
var sharePhoto = function() {
    ezfb.api("/me/photos",
       "POST",
       {
           "source": content,
           "message": "This is a test Photo"
       },
       function (response) {
           console.log("shared", response);
           if (response && !response.error) {
              /* handle the result */
           }
       });
};

ezfb.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if(response.status === 'connected') {
        console.log("already conntected", response);
        sharePhoto();
    } else {
        ezfb.login(function(response) {
            // Do something with response.
            console.log("FB",response);
            sharePhoto();
        }, {scope: 'public_profile,email,user_photos,publish_actions'});
    }
});
```

The console-log is:

```
already conntected {status: "connected", authResponse: Object} 
shared {error: {code: 324, message: "(#324) Requires upload file", type: "OAuthException"}}
```

My questions are:

- Whats the expected format of my variable *content*? How do I need to
  encode it?
- Do I have to manipulate the request Headers of the request? How?

Thanks a lot for your help!

**Edit:** Console-Log added

Comment: Can you post your network log from the developer tools of your browser?

Comment: I added the console log to my post.

Comment: A bit more information would be helpful. If you're on Chrome, go to the network tab in your development tools, click on the request that is failing, and copy all the headers, including request and response, as long as the response.